# Waiting for debugger to connect

Tags: debugging, mono, xamarin.ios, ios-simulator, monodevelop

(excuse me for my english!)

When i debug my app, the simulator is opening but with nothing... 
in the monodevelop ide, it shows alert box with message "Waiting for debugger to connect..."

sometime, the simulator ask me the applicaton to load... but which?

why?

in the past, i had monodevelop 2.6 installed, then monodevelop 2.6 and 2.8 together, NOW: only monodevelop 2.8

can somebody help me?

how i can resolve all this troubles?

thank you

Comment: Which (exact) versions of MonoTouch and MonoDevelop do you have installed? Also you can enable verbose output by adding "-v -v -v" to the additional mtouch arguments, and information about any connection failures should be printed to the application output.

Comment: Monodevelop version is 2.8.6.5 instead MonoTouch version 5.2.5 (Evaluation). There isn't no verbose output when i'm trying to simulate my simple application (HelloWorld) on IphoneSimulator (version 5) after setup additional arguments -v-v-v. Only output is Starting iOS simulator 5.0

Launching application now situation is that: simulator starting up but my application doesn't start and it doesn't installed on simulator. MonoDevelop shows "waiting for debugger to connect..." but doesn't happens

help me

Comment: What's the exact message from the simulator when **sometime, the simulator ask me the applicaton to load...** happens ? Could it be asking your to switch to another version of iOS ? (e.g. with a Switch... button)

Comment: It might be an issue with Xcode, can you try installing the latest Xcode on your system (Xcode 4.3.1)?

Comment: I had the same problem on my mac mini (mid 2011) with 2gb of ram. Now I have 5gb and all works just fine.

Comment: I've this same issue now and then. Running with 16Gb of memory, so that probably won't be the issue. Normally I totally quit the simulator and then start debugging again, which starts the simulator again. Sometimes I've to kill the app in the simulator/device first before it continues to start/connect/debug.

Answer (score 0):

Try to restart `MonoDevelop`. Then reset IOS Simulator `IOS Simulator >> Reset Content and Settings...` and then restart your `IOS Simulator`.