# Monodevelop: `Waiting for debugger`

Tags: debugging, mono, monodevelop

I am trying to debug [this Mono desktop software](https://github.com/hbons/SparkleShare/tree/master/SparkleShare/Linux) in Monodevelop.

I imported the SLN file, ran `Build all` with success, but when I press the `Debug` button I get this popup that stays waiting forever saying `Waiting for debugger`:

[image: Monodevelop: Waiting for debugger]

The output says:

> User assembly '/home/nico/src/SparkleShare/SparkleShare/bin/SparkleShare.exe' is missing. Debugger will now debug all code, not just user code.

My first line of code is a `Console.WriteLine` whose output does not appear anywhere.
Am I doing something wrong?

Monodevelop 3.0.3.2 on Ubuntu 2012.10.
Nothing special appears on the console with `monodevelop -v -v -v`.

When I press `Start Without Debugging` instead of `Start Debugging`, the app crashes immediately saying `The application exited with code: 255`, but I need Debug to find where the problem is.

When I press `Debug Application...` and select `bin/SparkleShare.exe`, Monodevelop does nothing. The UI does not react in any way, it is like I pressed nothing.

When I run the application from command line, it runs fine (no crash), but Monodevelop does not react in any way, so I can't use it to debug:

```
mono --debug  bin/SparkleShare.exe
```

Debugging in Monodevelop works fine with a solution created from scratch.

[Here is a hack to debug in Monodevelop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13740078/226958) that works here, but it is quite painful, and unsupported.

*Note: It is not the same problem as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9716141/waiting-for-debugger-to-connect), which is about MonoTouch waiting for a phone simulator... the suggestions over there are about the simulator or updating XCode... no simulator nor XCode here.*

Comment: check /home/nico/src/SparkleShare/... for the exe.  If it built properly, you should be able to manually run the app using mono.  That should be a starting point to start troubleshooting.  If it doesn't work, check man mono for some of the debugging flags you can pass.  It could be something as simple as monodevelop not finding the exe and is just not handling that situation appropriately.

Comment: @DaveFerguson: Command-line is actually how I run my app meanwhile. You are right, I guess it is just a simple configuration problem.

Answer (score 2):

MonoDevelop 2.8.6.3 is kinda old.

I recommend you upgrading to 3.x or even the master branch, which has a lot of improvements and probably fixes your issue.

Comment: Upgrading was probably a good thing, but unfortunately that does not solve the present problem. I added a few details to my question.

Comment: I recommend you to then open a bug in http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/ . Given that SparkleShare is open source, it will probably be a good enough testcase for them to replicate the problem, if you explain the steps to reproduce well enough.